# iOS Autolayout : Place a button exactly in the middle of two other buttons horizontally

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to build a view which looks something like this : [image]

The challenge I'm facing is I'm not able to identify the constraints that will be needed to place **Button2** exactly in the **center** of **Button1** and **Button3**.

All other constraints are satisfied, just struggling with this one. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: take one view ... add 3 buttons in it and give equal width to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed that buttons in an `UIView`. and set horizontally center in container constraint to it and give top,fixed height and width or leading and trailing constraint to it. And set top,leading,trailing and fixed height to other two buttons.

Or you can give equal width to every buttons, and manage constraints accordingly.

Main concern is take that label in one separate `UIView`. And then manage constraints accordingly.

Comment: This solved my problem, using an extra UIView was the solution! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Put `UIView`s between `Button1` and `Button2` and `Button2` and `Button3`. Set these 2 views as transparent and mark their widths as equal to each other. 
That should take care of it.